# Align 2 ExpandableListViews

Tags: android, xml

I have a problem aligning 2 ExpandableListViews and a floating action button. I am supposed to get on the same row list1,fab,list2 but I end up having list2 below list1. I can't get what I am doing wrong here. Any idea?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:hint="     Write your text..."
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:background="#71ABFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:background="#71ABFF"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/trans"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"></com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton>


    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/list2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Actual design

[image]

Comment: Attach reference image for actual and expected design.

Comment: Please post the full layout code (at least the parent of the ExpandableListViews) and an image that illustrates what you want to achieve

Comment: you need android:layout_toLeftOf, android:layout_below, .. to define which item is right/left/below/ wich other item